# Code for Heart Rate Detection using PPG Sensor

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano

I am using the "MIKROE Heart Rate 3 click" PPG sensor (https://www.mikroe.com/heart-rate-3-click) and an Arduino Nano (https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-nano) to find heart rate estimation. Does someone know what code to use?

The library associated to the MIKROE is unavailable, therefore, I tried using the AFE4404 library through the code shown below and running a separate algorithm for finding heart rate, however, once I ran it, the monitor and plotter do not provide any peaks that must be used to run the algorithms.

PPG TEST CODE (used previously but do not know how to find heart rate)

```cpp
/*
 * AFE4404 Basic Read library example.
 * https://github.com/rakshithbk/AFE4404-Library
 * 
 * On Arduino Uno -  | AFE4404 | Uno Pin
 *                   | I2C_Dat | A4
 *                   | I2C_Clk | A5
 * get_led_val() will return uint32_t values.
 * 
 * Advanced - you can modify the sample period and other
 * parameters in the library files (refer AFE4404 datasheet)
 */


#include <Wire.h>
#include <AFE_connect.h>

AFE A;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AFE4404 basic readings -\n");
  A.init();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("LED 1 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led1_val());
  Serial.print("\t LED 2 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led2_val());
  Serial.print("\t LED 3 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led3_val());
  Serial.println();
}
```

GitHub
rakshithbk/AFE4404-Library
Basic Library of AFE4404 for Arduino Uno. Contribute to rakshithbk/AFE4404-Library development by creating an account on GitHub.